# Call method of Controller1 into another method of Controller2 in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-security

I did Google  a lot to find my problem but I couldn't and sorry If this question already on the stack overflow because I have not find it.

First let take a look into the code

```
@Controller
public class Controller1 {
    @RequestMapping(value = "URL", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView methodHandler(Parameters) { 

    }

    public int calculation(int i){
        //Some Calcucation
        return i;
    }
}
```

and second controller is

```
@Controller
public class Controller2 {
    @RequestMapping(value = "URL", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView methodHandler(Parameters) { 
        //In this I want to call the calculation(1) method of controller1.
    }
}
```

My question is that is there any way to call the method of calculation() of controler1 in to controller2. But remember  I don't want to make method static in controller1.Is there anyway to call it without make it static?

Thanks
Yasir

Comment: Put the metod in a helper class.

Comment: this method are using attributes of controller1 , so therefore I cannot put it into HelperClass

Comment: Controller should not have methods related to business logic. create a separate classes for such methods and then use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create service bean  for example in configuration file (or use @ one of the annotaions) and inject it into controller. For example ()

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyService myService(){
        return new MyService();
    }

}


@Controller
public class Controller1 {

    @Autowire
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "URL", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView First(Parameters) { 
        myService.calculation();
    }
}

@Controller
public class Controller2 {

    @Autowire
    private MyBean myBean;

    @RequestMapping(value = "URL", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView First(Parameters) { 
        myService.calculation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controllers should not call each other. If there is a logic which needs to be used by both controllers, it is much better to put that into separate bean, which will be used by both controllers. Then you can simply inject that bean to whicheveer controller neccessary. Try not to put any business logic to controllers, try tu put it to specialized class instead which will be web independent if possible and will accept web agnostic business data as user email, account number etc. No http request or response. This way your class with actual logic is reusable and can be unit tested much more easily. Also, if there is state, it should be contained in your classes outside controllers. Controllers should be stateless and not contail any state at all.

When using MVC pattern and you are deciding where to put your logic, you should separate business logic into model and into controllers you should put only logic regarding user interaction, [as explained in this stack overflow post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165444/where-to-put-business-logic-in-mvc-design).